# Property similar to connectedness

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, connectedness

Recall that $X$ is *connected* if $X$ cannot be written as the union of nonempty open sets with empty intersection.

Consider the following similar property:

> $X$ is *good* if $X$ cannot be written as the union of connected open sets with disconnected intersection.

In other words, $X$ is good if, for all open connected sets $A$ and $B$ with $A\cup B=X$, we have that $A\cap B$ is connected.

$\Bbb R^n$ is good for all $n$. $S^n$ and $\rm\Bbb RP^n$ are good for all $n\ge2$. In fact, if $H_1(X;G)=0$ for some $G$, then $X$ is good. This comes from the portion of the reduced Mayer–Vietoris sequence around $\widetilde H_0(A\cap B)$.

Are these the only good spaces? Or are there good spaces with $H_1(X;G)\ne0$ for all $G$? I have no idea how to approach this..

Comment: what about $X= \mathbb RP^2$??

Comment: @Anubhav.K $H_1(\Bbb {RP}^2; \Bbb Z/3) = 0$.

Comment: @BalarkaSen ohhh, I missed it out, I though for some $G$. If the qes is for some $G$, then $\mathbb RP^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: But the question is _not_ for some $G$, for which there are obvious counterexamples. It clearly asks for good spaces with nontrivial homology in all coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

$\require{AMScd}$I'd rather think about the negation of your first condition. So call a space *bad* if there exists a decomposition $A \cup B$ into connected open sets with disconnected intersection. Call a space *semi-bad* if there exists a decomposition into open sets $A \cup B$ such that the induced map on relative homology $\tilde H_0(A \cap B) \to \tilde H_0(A) \oplus \tilde H_0(B)$ is not injective.

As you say in your post, semi-bad implies that $H_1(X;G)$ is nonzero for all $G$.

**Theorem**: If $H^1(X;\Bbb Z) \neq 0$, and $X$ is a CW complex, then $X$ is semi-bad.

This is because there are canonical bijections between $$H^1(X;\Bbb Z) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(X;\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z) \cong [X,S^1].$$
(The first isomorphism is the universal coefficient theorem, the second is an appendix in Hatcher chapter 1 + the fact that $H_1$ is the abelanization of $\pi_1$. The latter bijection sends each homomorphism to a map that induces that homomorphism.)

So our assumption implies that there is a homotopically nontrivial map $p: X \to S^1$. Decompose $S^1$ into $U \cup V$ the obvious slight thickenings of the northern and southern hemispheres. Then $p^{-1}(U) \cup p^{-1}(V)$ is a semi-bad decomposition of $X$. To see this, note first that Mayer-Vietoris is natural under maps of triples $(X,U,V)$, so we get a diagram

$$\begin{CD}
H_1(X;\Bbb Z) @>>> \tilde H_0(p^{-1}(U) \cap p^{-1}(V);\Bbb Z) @>>> \tilde H_0(p^{-1}(U)) \oplus H_0(p^{-1}(V);\Bbb Z)\\
@Vp_*VV @VVV @VVV \\
\Bbb Z =H_1(S^1;\Bbb Z) @>\cong>> \tilde H_0(U \cap V;\Bbb Z) @>>> H_0(U;\Bbb Z) \oplus H_0(V;\Bbb Z) = 0\\
\end{CD}$$

A diagram chase along with the fact that $p_*$ is nonzero easily shows from here that this is a semi-bad decomposition of $X$.

---

We should now relate this to your condition: that $H_1(X;G) \neq 0$ for all $G$. If $H_1(X;\Bbb Z)$ is finitely generated, this implies that $H^1(X;\Bbb Z)$ is nonzero (invoke the classification theorem of finitely generated abelian groups and your assumption for $G = \Bbb Q$). I have not thought about this in further generality. As a sign of danger, think about the universal coefficient theorem, 3F.12 in Hatcher, and [Whitehead's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_problem), known to be independent of ZFC.

One might also be interested in relating the notion of semi-badness to the notion of badness. I have not made any attempt to do so.

Comment: I think there is a typo, in the diag the 2nd row's last term would be reduced homology